# React : Need a faster way to filter data and setState

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I need to make a menu list for a restaurant app, and the menu data is categorized in **American, Chinese, Indian, Italian**. I need to loop over all these to render it somehow in the scrollspy type menu.
For that I have **configured the backend to send in ALL the ITEMS at once** and need to filter and sort it as per the category on the react side.

DATA STRUCTURE :

```
{
   _id: 5eef61450bd95e1f5c8f372f
   name: "Burger"
   category: "American"
   price: "100"
   isVeg: false
   __v: 0
}
```

The way i am doing is seems too slow and I believe there is **GOT TO BE A FASTER/EFFECIENT WAY**. Please suggest, because my way makes me want to puke.

```
const CheckForms = () => {
    const [american, setAmerican] = useState([]);
    const [italian, setItalian] = useState([]);
    const [indian, setIndian] = useState([]);
    const [chinese, setChinese] = useState([]);
    
    const fetchList = async () => {
        try {
            const res =  await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/items`);
            const list =  res.data.response;  
            let ch = [];
            let ind = [];
            let am = [];
            let it = [];
            list.forEach(function(each){
                if (each.category === "Chinese") ch.push(each)
                else if (each.category === "Indian") ind.push(each)     
                else if (each.category === "American") am.push(each)     
                else if (each.category === "Italian") it.push(each)     
                else console.log('undefined category');
            });
            setAmerican(am);
            setIndian(ind);
            setChinese(ch);
            setItalian(it);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response);
        };
    };
    useEffect(()=> {
        fetchList();
    }, []);

    let render;
    if (indian.length > 0 && american.length > 0 && chinese.length > 0 && italian.length > 0) {
        render = (
            /*********************************
             *  AND FURTHER RENDERING LOGIC :( 
             ********************************/
        );
    };
```

Comment: Iterating array and filtering into "bins" or categories is an `O(n)` operation, not much you can do there to make it any faster. Do you just have a "hunch" that it can be faster (or more efficient) or do you have actual performance issue with the code above? From what I can tell, about the only "improvements" from here come at readability and/or code maintenance (i.e. if you need to add/remove categories). @HMR's solution has higher complexity, `O(n^2)` because of the inner array::concat, but allows this category handling automatically by using a Map.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reduce:

```js
const list = [
  { category: 'Chinese', name: 'one-1' },
  { category: 'Chinese', name: 'one-2' },
  { category: 'Indian', name: 'two' },
];
const groups = list.reduce(
  (result, item) =>
    result.set(
      item.category,
      (result.get(item.category) || []).concat(item)
    ),
  new Map()
);
console.log('Chinese',groups.get('Chinese'));
console.log('Indian',groups.get('Indian'));
```